# Animation 2d for a game. using Libgdx

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I'm studying for making a game at university.
I have a little problem, I need help to set a 2D animation for my game (bounce classic game).
I don't know how to load and use a `TextureRegion[][]` because with normal animation (made by 4 png) it works well, but with matrix of png doesn't work

This is my class animations

```
public abstract class Animations extends Sprite {

    protected TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas("sprites/Animation_light_Ball.atlas");

    protected Body body;

    protected TextureRegion ballStand;

    protected Array<TextureRegion> frames;

    protected float radius = 42;
    protected float stateTimer;
    private static final int BOUNDS_WIDTH = 90;
    private static final int BOUNDS_HEIGHT = 90;

    public Animations() {
    }


    public Animations(final String nameRegion) {
        setRegion(new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion(nameRegion),0,0,120,120));
        setBounds(0,0,BOUNDS_WIDTH,BOUNDS_HEIGHT); 
    }
    public Animation setAnimation(final int startFrame, final int endFrame, final String animationName,
            final int height, final int width) {
        final float duration = 0.12f;
        frames = new Array<>();
        for (int i = startFrame; i < endFrame; i++) {
            frames.add(new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion(animationName), i * 120, 0, height, width));
        }
        return new Animation(duration, frames);
    }

    public void cleanFrames() {
        frames.clear();
    }

    public void dispose() {
        atlas.dispose();
    }

    public void draw(final Batch batch) {
        super.draw(batch);
    }

    protected abstract void update(float dt);


}
```

This is my class ballViewImpl

```
public class BallViewImpl extends Animations implements BallView {

    public World world;
    public Body body;

    private static final int BOUNDS_WIDTH = 90;
    private static final int BOUNDS_HEIGHT = 90;

    public State currentState;
    public State previousState;

    private TextureRegion ballStand;
    private Animation rollingBall;
    private float stateTimer;
    private Ball ball;
    private boolean rollingRight;

    public BallViewImpl() {
        rollingRight= false;
        ballStand = new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion("Animation_light_ball-1"),0,0,120,120);
        rollingBall = setAnimation(0,4,"Animation_light_ball-1",120,120);
        setBounds(0,0,BOUNDS_WIDTH,BOUNDS_HEIGHT);
    }

     private TextureRegion setSprite(final float delta) {
            TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion();
            region = getFrame(delta);
            if ((body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0 || !rollingRight) && !region.isFlipX()) {
                region.flip(true, false);
                rollingRight = false;
            } else if (rollingRight && region.isFlipX()) {
                region.flip(true, false);
                rollingRight = true;
            }
            return region;
        }

    @Override
    public void setBall(Ball ball) {
        this.ball = ball;
        this.body = ball.getBody();

    }

    @Override
    public float getStateTimer() {
        return stateTimer;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        rollingRight = ball.isRolling();
        setPosition(body.getPosition().x - getWidth()/2, body.getPosition().y - getHeight()/2);
        setRegion(setSprite(dt));

    }

    private TextureRegion getFrame(float dt) {
         previousState = currentState;
         currentState = ball.getState();  //ballimplement
         stateTimer = currentState == previousState ? stateTimer +dt : 0;

         TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion();
         switch(currentState) {
         case ROLLING:
             region = rollingBall.getKeyFrame(stateTimer,true);
             break;
         case FALLING:
         case STANDING:
         default:
             region = ballStand;
             break;
         }

         return region;
    } 

    @Override
    public void draw(final Batch batch) {
        super.draw(batch);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does your assignment require you to use the Sprite class? Sprite is a super-optimized class that conflates assets with game state, and in my opinion inappropriate to use for almost any game. It has its use as the type used internally for particles, but otherwise it leads to convoluted code. It's an even bigger hack to be loading a TextureAtlas inside it. I recommend googling and reading about "Composition over Inheritance" in object oriented programming.

Comment: In my case I needed to use ```Animation<TextureRegion>``` instead of only ```Animation``` and the same for the ```Array<TextureRegion>``` instead of ```Array``` only too.